# How can I get the shading from Solid shading mode into Rendered shading mode?

Tags: rendering, shaders

[image]

I was trying to do some hard surface modelling, but when I finished, and started to set materials in the material preview mode, I noticed that solid mode has a much better look than my materials, which is clearly because of the shading which appears in solid mode but not in the material preview. So is there a way to get this type of shading in the rendered view?

Comment: The quick way to do it would be to go in the header menu > View > Viewport Render Image but I guess you're limited and you'd better try to find a similar shader than the one you see in Solid mode

Comment: tq moonboots , i got the desired result , thank you , i also got to know how to make an animation in this way

Comment: in the same menu > Viewport Render Animation, I guess you need to setup the output folder in the Output panel

Comment: You can also use regular rendering if you switch the render engine to "Workbench" in the render properties tab. note you will have to tweak the render settings there too